# Undo cursor move?

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, shortcut, 3d-cursor

How can I undo when I move the cursor, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't work? I would prefer a keyboard shortcut, but any method will do, although I'd like to avoid scripts if possible.

Comment: I think the closest thing you can do without scripts is adding empties before moving the cursor. The only reasonable solution I can think of is writing an addon which stores the cursor coordinates before the cursor is moved, then puts the cursor back when Ctrl Z is pressed. (if the cursor wasn't the last action, then it could undo normally)

Comment: Yes, this is always what I'm looking for. I think it is very helpful for blender to support this. However, there are [a few addons](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=82040) designed specifically to this, with some other enhanced features. You can turn them on in Blender.

Comment: @LeonCheung Could you add this as an answer, I was not aware that the plugins exist but they are very useful.

Comment: @stacker Sorry for late reply, I saw poor did it. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try [Cursor Control](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Cursor_Control) addon.

[image]

*Note:* To overwrite your actions you only need to go back in history.

As everywhere in blender you can <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the **arrow buttons** of the cursor history to assign shortcuts for navigate back and forth:

[image]