# How to avoid accidentally relocating the 3d-cursor?

Tags: 3d-cursor

Is there anyway to help avoid accidentally relocating the 3d-cursor?

You have all of these complex keystrokes in Blender like (CTR+ALT+SHIFT+C),
 but yet all it takes is a simple accidental left mouse button click to re-locate the cursor. 
How many hundreds of times I have done this and then had to move the 3d-cursor back where it was. Moving the 3d cursor is not stored in the Undo buffer, so you can't "undo" a relocation of the 3d cursor.
It is very frustrating.

Comment: depends on where you want to have the cursor. Try shift+c to set it back to the center.

Comment: Added my own answer, see below.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/undo-cursor-move. It is told there about *undoing* while yours is about *preventing*, still it can be useful

Comment: Ok, that is a useful link. I just changed the title of the question from "Preventing moving the 3d cursor?" to "How to avoid accidentally relocating the cursor?". Because, it seems it is not possible to "Lock" the 3d cursor in blender. So the answer below now agrees with the question.

Answer (score 6):

I saw the same question with solution from a long time ago:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-236492.html

I went to the user preferences and switched "Set 3d cursor" from "LMB" to "Shift + LMB".
Now I can no longer accidentally move it.

Answer (score 1):

In **Blender 2.80**, you can now [HIIIDE](https://youtu.be/yyCepAM7Ftc?t=287) the 3D cursor.

Click on the **Overlays** menu:

[image]

And deselect this little thing here:

[image]

*Et voilà!*

Comment: This only hides it, you can still select a 3d point